# Only capture 6 numbers after '~' in src tag javascript - regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have some code I am using to capture the `src` attribute of an image
`$('div.image').attr('src')`

which returns

```
/bookclubid-d-20150515113608427~421865_alt3.jpg
```

I only want to capture the 6 numbers following the `~`. The best I've been able to come up with so far is

```
$('div.image').attr('src').replace(/^[^~]+~/, '').replace(/\D+/g, '')
```

which is not capturing only 6, instead every number past the `~` How would I limit the capture to strictly 6 numbers following `~` and make this into one `.replace()`?

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var src = "/bookclubid-d-20150515113608427~421865_alt3.jpg";
console.log(src.split('~')[1].substring(0, 6));
```

Comment: UGH! I was so focus on using regex I didn't think of the other options! Thanks so much!